# $\sqrt{5}BA \leq PA +PB+\sqrt{2}PC$

Tags: geometry, inequality, geometric-inequalities

Let $ABC$ be an isosceles right triangle ($\angle B=90^o$) and a point $P$ in its plane. Prove the inequality $\sqrt{5}BA \leq PA +PB+\sqrt{2}PC$. Find all poins $X$ for which the equality holds.

It might be the most difficult problem I have ever met. First, I thought it has a relation to the lemma $\frac{PA}{a}+\frac{PB}{b}+\frac{PC}{c}\geq \sqrt 3$ . But no! The equality holds differently from the problem. I try to create a new isosceles right triangle with side AC but it does not work. Any idea for this, thank!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $AB=1$, $A(1,0),$ $B(0,0)$, $C(0,1)$ and $P(x,y)$.

Thus, by Minkowski:
$$PA+PB+\sqrt2PC=\sqrt{(x-1)^2+y^2}+\sqrt{x^2+y^2}+\sqrt{2(x^2+(y-1)^2)}=$$
$$=\sqrt{(x-1)^2+(-y)^2}+\sqrt{(-y)^2+(-x)^2}+\sqrt{(-x+y-1)^2+(x+y-1)^2}\geq$$
$$\geq\sqrt{(x-1-y-x+y-1)^2+(-y-x+x+y-1)^2}=\sqrt5=\sqrt5BC.$$

Comment: @user628755 I got that the equality occurs on the circle $\left(x-\frac{1}{3}\right)^2+\left(y-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2=\frac{1}{36}.$